# What is the best way to show the Facebook "Like" widget?

Tags: facebook, social

I am working on an e-commerce aggregator site. I need to place a Facebook like widget. Now, I am not sure what is the best way to get the user to like the Facebook page. What would be the best way to get user to like the page on Facebook? Should I go ahead with the traditional Facebook "Like" Widget or would a FB icon linking to the Facebook page be better? Also, what should be the placement for the same?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few questions here.

The best way to get user to `like` your page would be via the standard `like` button. Directing them from your website to the facebook page and counting on them to `like` the facebook page there is a longer flow of action than the user just clicking the `like` button on your webpage.

While many people like to place facebook `like` widgets in their headers, I think that sacrifices too much of an important spot - but ultimately it is a design choice and depends on how much stress you want to put on the feature.

As for what kind of button it should be, stay consistent with [facebook's guidelines](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php), so that users can easily identify the button and it's standardized functionality they already know from other sites adhering to the same recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a particular reason for really wanting the visitors to visit the facebook page (such as trying to market your site through facebook), it's much more user-friendly just to let them link it on the site without redirecting to facebook.

If the main point of the page is to get the user to click the "like" button, the lower-right corner of the site would be a good place to put the link.  That's the last place the user will reach, so it's an ideal location for a [call to action](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/design-theory/understanding-the-z-layout-in-web-design/) if you don't have some other call to action already on the page.  Putting the link in a sidebar or heading directly next to the content that you want to be liked could also be effective because it associates the action with the content.

Facebook also allows applications to have [built-in likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-actions/likes/) (where the user's "like" of your custom like icon translates to a "like" on facebook as well) under certain circumstances, so you may find those useful depending on the purpose of your page.  You might be able to associate the custom like button with another function on your site, such as "like item and add to cart" so that you gain an increased rating on facebook even as the users use your site.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear it's the '[Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)' function we're talking here?

There's obviously a difference between a 'Like' and a 'Follow'.

Assuming it's Like, I agree with both JonW and 3nafish, use the 'on page' Facebook Like.

Not only does it reduce the friction of the action, is the standard and widely understod behaviour but a visible count offers 'social proof' of the popularity of the item.

You can either use Facebooks default like (link above), of if you want multiple networks you can try AddThis or ShareIt.

The only downside of using Facebook's button or a third party solution is it can often be a performance drag. If possible put it toward the end of your markup and position it with CSS so it doesn't prevent other page elements from loading first.

Alternatively I recently saw this sript; http://socialitejs.com/ which delays the dynamic elements loading until the user interacts with it which might help, though I can't vouch for it's usefulness.